# Nested Loop In C#

Tags: c#, loops

I'm doing a simple c# exercise. Here's the problem: Write a program called SquareBoard that displays the following n×n (n=5) pattern using two nested for-loops. Here's my code:

```
Sample output:
# # # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #
```

Here's my code:

```
for (int row = 1; row <=5; row++) {
    for (int col = 1;col <row ; col++)
    {
        Console.Write("#");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

But it doe's not work .can anyone help me. thank you..

Comment: The problem is with this part in the second `for` loop: `col < row`. The value of `row` changes in every iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Have you tried using debugger ?

Comment: @Jay, try a bit more to solve your exercises by yourself before posting them here. This is their purpose. I am sure you could find the answer to your question

Answer (score 8):

```
int n = 5;
for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
    for (int col = 1;col <= n; col++) {
        Console.Write("# ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
{

    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
        Console.Write("# ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: @OptimusCrime, it will produce 6x5

Comment: Oops, I used <= instead of <. Copied it brainlessly from the original.

Comment: dont Hard code(not a good practice), declare the value as int as did by OptimusCrime.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
col <row
```

is causing you problems.

Change it to:

```
col <=5
```

and it should work

Comment: No. It would run only 4 times. It should be `col <= 5`.

Comment: yah, i know.  just copied at first, coz 'row' is the issue. fixed now

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
int n = 5;
for (int row = 1; row <=n; row++) 
{
    string rowContent = String.Empty;
    for (int col = 1;col <=n; col++)
    {
        rowContent += "# ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(rowContent);
}
```

Of course you might want to use a `StringBuilder` if you are doing this kind of thing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration, you compare `col` to `row`, and they are both 1. You check if the one is higher than the other, and the second loop never runs. Rewrite like this:

```
 for (int row = 1; row <=5; row++) {    
            for (int col = 1;col <= 5 ; col++)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
 }
```

The second iteration needs to run from 1 to 5 every time.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely works:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("# ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++)

    for(int j=0 ; j <5 ; j++)
    Console.Write("#");

Console.WriteLine();
```